# Python matplotlib image + points plot

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot, overlay

I want to plot some points on an image and I'm using the following code for it:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.imshow(img)
ax.plot(newModel[:, 0], newModel[:, 1])
ax.set_title("Model tooth " + str(model_number) + ": new model after " + str(it_count) + " iterations")
fig.savefig("Fit_models/" + str(file_number) + "_model_" + str(model_number) + "_newModel.png")
```

It works, but this is the result:

[image]

I'd like for the axis to just go from 0 to the image shape instead of starting at -500.
Also I'd prefer if this could be saved on the full resolution of the image, instead of on a 800x600.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the limits you can use:

```
ax.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
ax.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])
```

And for the resolution you can use the dpi keyword:

```
fig.savefig(fname, dpi=400)
```

You can adjust the dpi to get the desired resolution.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Is it also possible to remove some of the whitespace around the plot?

Comment: Sure. Use `plt.show()` to show the plot and adjust the white space using the `Configure subplots` tool to your needs. Then set these values in your script with `plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1, top=..., left=..., right=...)`. Please also accept my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Ok I got rid of the whitespace left and right, but above and below the whitespace is still there. Doesn't seem like any of those parameters affect it.

Comment: You can also try `plt.tight_layout()`. See also it's [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html).